# How can I remove the first byte multiple rows of varbinary data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I reworked a VB script to log parts over a final operation at work, but it added an additional byte at the beginning I would like to remove.

[image: Test table, need to remove the first two zeros]

[image: This is the format of the table]

Comment: SQL substring() (and likely other string functions) work on binary types too.

Comment: Someone edited my post, I'm very new to SQL so could you please elaborate? I have about 22,000 rows to modify

Comment: what is the original data type of this data?

Comment: Something like this: `update yourtable set data = substring(data, 2, len(data)) where substring(data, 1, 1) = char(0)`. I'm not sure about where conditon - you need to try yourself.

Comment: in general, leading zeros in varbinary should not affect anything, it should not cause any issue

Comment: @YairMaron Except that unnecessary leading zeros in binary data may kill any possible internal data structure or signature or similar information. Really. Take some image or zip file in binary form, open it in hex editor, prepend data with zero or two - what you get?

Comment: @YairMaron In my case, the leading zeros causes a byte shift. The data is binary data I believe, read from a PLC as a mix of BCD, ASCII, binary, and int.

Comment: @Arvo Your statement worked as-is! Thank you

Comment: Well, then you have option to mark my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL `substring()` (and likely some other string functions) work on binary types too.
Something like this could work:

```
update yourtable 
set data = substring(data, 2, len(data)) 
where substring(data, 1, 1) = char(0).
```

I'm not sure about where conditon - you need to try yourself.